# Wordpress User Nicename and profile URL seem to conflict

Tags: php, wordpress

I have created a site on WordPress whereby users register on the front end, create a profile, and enter information about themselves - pretty straightforward.

On registration, I automatically force there username to be /name-surname.
If there is someone with the exact same username (meaning the same name and surname) I add a consecutive integer into the end of the username. For example: john-smith-2; john-smith-3 etc.

I do this using the following code:

```
 add_filter( 'pre_user_login', 'name_as_username' );
    function name_as_username( $user_login ) {
    
    if(isset($_POST['first_name'])) $first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
    if(isset($_POST['last_name'])) $last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
    
    {
        $user_login = $_POST['first_name'].'-'.$_POST['last_name'];
    
    $original_login = $user_login;
    $i = 1;
    
    do {
    //Check in the database here
    $exists = get_user_by( 'login', $user_login ) !== false;
    if($exists) {
        $i++;
        $user_login = $original_login .'-'. $i;
        }
    }  while($exists);
        }
        
    return $user_login;
    }
```

This all works great on registration, and does what it is supposed to do.

Elsewhere on the site, I have created a shortcode that I use to redirect users to their own "profile page". The shortcode looks up the user's username, and redirects it to a unique URL that contains that username. For example: [www.mywebsite.com/john-smith-2](http://www.mywebsite.com/john-smith-2)

This is the code that I use:

```
add_shortcode('bt_redirect_user_link', 'bt_redirect_user_link');
function bt_redirect_user_link ($atts) {
    // check if user is logged in
    if (is_user_logged_in()) {
        // get current user object
        $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    
        // get user nickname
        $user_nickname = $current_user->data->user_nicename;

        // set the link href
        $link_href = '/athlete/' . $user_nickname;

        // output the link html
        return $link_href;
    }
}
```

This all works great on the frontend. Users can enter and update their information across the site, and then click on the shortcode to get back to their own profile page.

Bizarrely, if I update a users information **using the *Users* tab in Wordpress**, the next time I click the above shortcode on the frontend, it looks up the users username and adds an extra number to it.

Below is an example of a profile that has been updated multiple times in the backend *Users* tab of Wordpress:

[image]

**Can anybody see a conflict in the two pieces of code that could be causing this issue?** It's boggling my mind!

Alternatively, is there a better way to go about this?

Thanks very much!

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the base idea just that this is firing each time a username after it has been sanitized. @see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_user_login/

Comment: Thanks @amarinediary! So are you saying that each time I update a user in the Wordpress console, it sanitizes the username and triggers the function to run? Or are you saying that I need to sanitize the username on registration so that the update doesn't trigger the function. Sorry, I'm new to PHP, so I'm struggling to understand the documentation.

Comment: Exactly every-time a user is being updated/created the function fires. A better approach would be to use an action which would fire on user register @see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/user_register/. You can easily verify this by updating your example username, it should ad a -2 at the end of your current example user.

Comment: Hi @amarinediary. I'm wondering if you can help me with the code snippet that would fire on registration? I have been trying for weeks to get something working, but I haven't been successful.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume that when a user register on your website, the "first name" and "last name" are updated at the same time the user is actually registered in the database.

We can use the `user_register` hook.

> Fires immediately after a new user is registered.

- See @ https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/user_register/

The plan is to "intercept" the registration and do the modification to the `user_nicename`. Why the `user_nicename` ? Because it is the one used for the user url profile.

`The user_login` is a sensible thing, in the WordPress environment you can easier login through the `user_login` or the `user_email`. Changing that might disturb some people. Also, from an anonymity standpoint, it's better to have a username that has nothing to do with your first and last name...

> **This is untested.**

```
<?php

/**
 * Intercept the registration process,
 * Update the user user_nicename with the first_name and last_name,
 * Handles duplicates by adding an increment to the user_nicename
 * The following will fires immediately after a new user is registered.
 * 
 * @param $user_id (int) User ID.
 * @param $userdata (array) The raw array of data passed to wp_insert_user().
 */
add_action( 'user_register', 'wpso72002100' );

function wpso72002100( $user_id, $userdata ) {

    //we verify that the first_name and last_name are set
    if ( empty( $userdata['first_name'] ) || empty( $userdata['last_name'] ) )
        return;

    //user_nicename must be unique and sanitized
    $user_nicename = sanitize_title_with_dashes( $userdata['first_name'] . '-' . $userdata['last_name'] . '-' . $user_id ); //@see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/sanitize_title_with_dashes/

    //finaly we update the user with our new user_nicename
    $buffer = array (
        'ID' => $user_id, 
        'user_nicename' => $user_nicename,
    );

    wp_update_user( $buffer ); //@see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_update_user/

}
```

Now let me share my two cents. Using the user first name and last name in a url are probably considered bad practice. In an age where personal data is such a sensible subject I wouldn't even consider it... Also you could end up by indexing all your user profile making it really easy for anyone to get some personal data, even just the name in the url.

Instead you can generate a pseudo random number based on the user registration date and id. This will effectively prevent data scraping and iteration and keep the user profile anonymous from a url standpoint. The following is what I'm currently describing:

```
//...
$user_nicename = sanitize_title_with_dashes( $user_id . str_replace( array( '-', ' ', ':', ), '', get_userdata( $user_id )->user_registered ) );
//...
```

Comment: Thank you @amarinediary. The code did not work as I was using a plugin that conflicted with the user_register call, but your answer lead me to that conclusion. I have managed to solve with a little help from others.

Comment: glad to hear it, good luck with your project !